Is using a virtualised android instance or emulator within "operating system vendor supported or warranted configurations"?
The NHS app is required for certain features of the NHS.  In the terms of service it states:

9.1. You may not use the NHS App:

on any device or operating system that has been modified outside the mobile device or operating system vendor supported or warranted configurations. This includes devices that have been "jail-broken" or "rooted"


If one ran a virtualised instance of an open source android version as per instructions on the vendors web site would that meet these requirements?  What about using an emulator?
It has been the case that this has been required to use the app in some instances.

problem is "device or operating system" doesn't seem to cover "emulator", which is more like a "virtual device".  The intent really seems to be about the OS or hardware the app is running in, so an emulator provided by Android doesn't seem like it would break this term and is certainly not "jail-broken" or "rooted".   It's fully supported by Google and is commonly used for testing.  I wouldn't say it's recommended for running an app, though.  You'll find that emulated hardware is no replacement for real device testing.

I write this answer to help you see the distinction between a question of law and a question of fact.
You have asked a factual question, not a question of law. To answer your question, one needs to determine whether in fact the specific "virtualised [or emulated] instance of an open source android version" is within the specific vendor's "supported or warranted configurations."
Certainly there are some factual questions that we can reasonably address at law.SE, like whether a hypothetical scenario falls within self-defence. In that case, the required elements of self-defence are well-established, either enumerated by statute or developed in case law, and we can apply that law to the circumstances. Even for those, the best approach is often to simply describe the law and leave it to readers to apply to the circumstances.
But the factual question presented here is about whether a circumstance falls within what a unique contractual term would require.
We have no special expertise at law.SE to do that factual investigation.
If the question intends to deem as a premise that the particular hypothetical instance is "quite specifically within the vendor of the open source android operating systems supported configurations" (as clarified in a comment to this answer) then yes, the instance is within the specific vendor's "supported or warranted configurations."
If you are simply curious how terms of a contract are interpreted, there are many other Q&As on this site explaining those principles. E.g.: how to interpret language in a contract.

The point is that it is quite specifically within the vendor of the open source android operating systems supported configurations, because it is following the instructions on their web site.  The only other device or operating system that is involved is a general purpose PC and a linux disto.  There is no obvious supported or warranted configuration to be outside of.

@User65535 It seems to me the "obvious" supported configuration is a mobile phone with Android.

@User65535: speaking as a software developer, I do not think it is "obvious" that the emulated environment is "supported". I mean, yes, they provide some degree of support, but there may be precedent somewhere, what degree of "support" is implied by the phrase "supported or warranted". I also wonder (and this may be a question of law) whether a device that has been "modified outside warranted conditions", but not outside of supported ones, is permitted per that contract language. The emulator I expect clearly is not "warranted", but the court would need evidence on that if it's relevant.

Perhaps as important, the condition is about "modifying" a device. It says nothing about using a device the NHS failed to anticipate you'd use. Fundamentally, if a lawyer (albeit not your lawyer) cannot tell you what this contract actually means, then you roll the dice or you don't. Is the NHS actually going to sue you?
